# how to get data form NSMutablearray in to NSString

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray, xml-parsing, nsmutabledictionary

Hello.......

in my apps, i have problem with xml parising .i have same tags differentiate  with integer value.each tag has different value.

now the problem me facing is accessing this value for that particular tag only.
plz  anybody have idea abat this.
let me know.

mean's the problem is that i have one MutableArray and all record in it. and i want to show some values in one view and reaming some value show in another view  and reaming in another view..
But the MutableArray is same..

and one more thing is that i want to get tag value

```
   <subject>XYZ</subject>
```

the output is subject i want.
i do not need of XYZ i need only subject..

sorry i can not show what i want but please understand my question and give me the answer

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use [`NSMutableDictionary`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) instead `NSMutableArray`.

From documentation.

> The NSMutableDictionary class declares the programmatic interface to
>   objects that manage mutable associations of keys and values. It adds
>   modification operations to the basic operations it inherits from
>   NSDictionary.

Comment: thnx bro But it is compensatory  use of NSMUtablArray

Comment: Actually in `dictionary` you could store both keys and value and it also provide the utility functions to access the keys and values.